# EPPlus AutoRisize cells to fit content -Remove unwanted spacing

Tags: c#, .net, excel, epplus

I have created an Excel document containing 2 columns in a sheet.

[image: Image of the document with one really wide column and the edge of the second.]

There is too much unwanted space between cells, such that the user has to scroll horizontally to see the second column. I have tried setting:

```
ws2.Cells.AutoFitColumns();
```

But this does not seem to work.

How can I make it work?

Answer (score 1):

Use `Style.Indent` to specific length

```
ws2.Cells["A1"].Style.Indent = 3;
```

Answer (score 1):

I would set the column width to a reasonable size (say 50) and then set the wrap to true, like this:

```
 summarystats.Column(2).Width = 50;
 summarystats.Column(2).Style.WrapText = true;
```